# AWS Event Bus fails to write logs to CloudWatch on a custom log group from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I have an AWS lambda whose job it is to consume logs from an external source and write these logs to a custom CloudWatch log group. Please note that this lambda is already writing logs to its own log group, that's not my question. What I want is for it to write the externally-derived logs to another CloudWatch group.

Following the AWS documentation, and using CloudFormation, I created an event bus and a rule that targets CloudWatch:

```
redacted
```

I have omitted most of the CloudFormation template for clarity, just leaving in the parts that seem relevant.

What I am finding is that the Lambda receives the logs (via Kinesis), processes them and sends them to the event bus in the code snippet below:

```
redacted
```

The last line above indicates that the event is sent to the event bus:

```
redacted
```

However the Event Bus, having i believe, received the event, does not send the event off to CloudWatch. Even if i manually create the log group: `${AWS::StackName}-form-log-batch-function` (I have kept the stack reference as a parameter to preserve anonymity).

I have checked the CloudFormation creation and all resources are present (confirmed by the Lambda not experiencing any exceptions, when it tries to send the event).

Anyone understand what I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can't write** to CloudWatch Logs (CWL) using  your `WebLogsEventBusLoggingRole` role. As [AWS docs](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/eventbridge/latest/userguide/resource-based-policies-eventbridge.html#cloudwatchlogs-permissions) explain, you **have to use CWL resource-based** permissions:

> When CloudWatch Logs is the target of a rule, EventBridge creates log streams, and CloudWatch Logs stores the text from the triggering events as log entries. To allow EventBridge to create the log stream and log the events, **CloudWatch Logs must include a resource-based policy** that enables EventBridge to write to CloudWatch Logs.

Sadly, you can't setup such permissions from vanila CloudFormation (CFN). This is **not supported**:

- [AWS::Events::Rule targetting Cloudwatch logs](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/351)

To do it from CFN, you have to create [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) in a form of a lambda function. The function would set CWL permissions using AWS SDK.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. It definitely clarifies things and i will now abandon this approach. I think if i were to have it trigger a custom resource lambda, as you suggest, then I could probably just have it write the logs under its default cloudwatch log group. This would satisfy my requirements as it separates the logging for the lambda that processes it from the lambda that logs the original entries.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon No problem. You can also have a lambda write to cloudwatch logs. So instead of pushing log data to EventBridge witch writes to CWL, you may have a lambda as target which does the writing to CWL.

Comment: yeah the problem is that there's no distinction between the log-group that process the events and the log-group that represents the events themselves. Otherwise, i would have had the original lambda just log the events directly. I wanted a separate log-group, not have it confused with the processor.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is helpful for others still looking for answers.

### Problem#1 I want Cloudformation to work

You can use the cloud formation from https://serverlessland.com/patterns/eventbridge-cloudwatch or [terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_resource_policy)

### Problem#2 Why is EventBridge not able to write to Cloudwatch Logs in general

Just like what was said above, in order for aws event bridge to write to cloudwatch there needs to be a resource policy (a Policy set on the destination, in this case, Cloudwatch Logs). However please note

- If you create a cloudwatch logs Target in the console a Resource Policy will be auto-generated for you, but the auto-generated one has a Twist

```json
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement":
        [
            {
                "Sid": "TrustEventsToStoreLogEvent",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal":
                {
                    "Service":
                    [
                        "events.amazonaws.com",
                        "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                },
                "Action":
                [
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:777777777:log-group:/*:*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

You will notice that the resource take the form of **/*:***
which mean the log group has to start with / if you are going to use the auto generated one.
So if your log group is not in the format /event/myloggroup/ then the policy will not help you.

So for example

| Target Log Group Name | ARN | Does it work? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| event-bridge-rule2 | arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:281458815962:log-group:event-bridge-rule2:* | Note the arn is missing starting / |
| /aws/events/helpme | arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:281458815962:log-group:/aws/events/helpme:* | Works like a charm |

My advice is put a policy that makes sense to you and doesn't rely on the automatic one.

Answer (score 0):

just create a `loggroup` with the name `/aws/events/<yourgroupname>` and it will work fine & also set `logs:*`